# test parameterized constructor that uses inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, patch

I want to test the function that looks like this

```
async def post_lookup(self, request: web.Request):
    response = await ZipcodeLookupModel(
        request.app[constants.CONNECTOR], session_store=request._state[constants.SESSION_STORAGE]
    ).lookup(request=request)
    return web.json_response(response)
```

The class `ZipcodeLookupModel` and its hierarchy looks like this

```
class ZipcodeLookupModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZipcodeLookupModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
class BaseModel:
    def __init__(self, connector=None, session_store=None):
        self.session_store = session_store
        self.connector = connector
        self.loop = get_running_loop()
        self.service_args = dict(connector=self.connector, loop=self.loop)
```

I want to `patch` that object creation

```
    with patch(
        "src.api.v1.zipcode.lookup.model.ZipcodeLookupModel",
        new=ZipcodeLookupModelStub()
    ):
        response = await client.session.post(url=f"http://{client.host}:{client.port}{path}", json=self.message)
        assert response.status == 200
        data = await response.json()
        assert data
```

I have created a stub object for the test

```
class ZipcodeLookupModelStub(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZipcodeLookupModelStub, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def lookup(self, request):
```

But when I run the test I get this error (on the line where the object is created in `post_lookup`)

```
super() argument 1 must be type, not ZipcodeLookupModelStub
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You patched the name with an *instance* of the stub, not the stub itself.

Comment: @chepner what do you mean? I thought with patch I would replace the invocation of the corresponding path with some custom object

Comment: It does. But you want the name to refer to the class `ZipcodeookupModelStub` itself, not an instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the name `ZipCodeLookupModel` with an instance of the class you want to use, not the class itself.

```
with patch(
    "src.api.v1.zipcode.lookup.model.ZipcodeLookupModel",
    new=ZipcodeLookupModelStub  # No parentheses
):
    response = await client.session.post(url=f"http://{client.host}:{client.port}{path}", json=self.message)
    assert response.status == 200
    data = await response.json()
    assert data
```

Comment: Now I got `super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`